# LWC Errors in Winter 24

Tags: lightning-web-components, winter24

I have some pretty standard LWC that were working fine last week. The sandbox is now on Winter 24, and I keep getting different errors when I view the component e.g.

```
Action.prototype.finishAction Error  [Assertion Failed!: Failed to find definition for dependency: lightning/spinner : undefined
Callback failed: 
or
Uncaught Assertion Failed!: Failed to find definition for dependency: lightning/button : undefined
```

Did something change in Winter 24 that I missed that I need to now change\update in the instance or LWC? Or is this a sandbox issue?

Comment: I'm getting the same issue in my sandbox post-Winter update, except I'm seeing it with my custom components. I hope to find out a solution soon and will definitely post here when I do.

Comment: Raising a case now...

Comment: This seem to be a multi customer issue and bug in winter'24, will update thread once I have more info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Salesforce posted a Known Issue yesterday that seems to cover this. I checked all my syntax and I found an extra `</template>` that wasn't causing problems before but was a problem now. Once I removed it everything started working again.

https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000uXc8mAAC/changes-for-lwc-api-version-590-are-applied-to-custom-components-with-version-580-and-earlier

Answer (score 2):

In Winter'24, lightning component was made HTML template parsing stricter and some users are impacted with this release update since the HTML code of custom components.

As a temporary workaround, component actually had an extra `"</template>"` tag and removing duplicate `</template>` should fix the issue.

```
<template>
<!--->
</template>
</template>

*Workaround*:    
<template>
<!--->
</template>
```

While product team has an internal bug *#W-14030988* for this patch fix and will be rolled out on 9/19-9/20(Safe Harbor).